# Video Pixelation in OSMF

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza, osmf, smil

I have created a custom player using osmf plugin but I have an issue in OSMF while i am playing  200kbps bitrate RTMP video.I have set buffer size by 2 sec and OSMFSettings.enableStageVideo by false.I found that the video is pixelated but i play same video in jwplayer 
then i found video is less pixelated i am attaching two images with this.
Can anybody tell how to solve this problem.

OSMFCustomPlayer
[image]

JWPlayer
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this with the JW Player.

Comment: I am using following https://account.jwplayer.com/#/publish/configure/internet

Comment: I mean a public url with your player embed. Thanks.

Comment: i have passed local wowza smil url in jwplayer

Comment: You need to provide something to debug if you want help here.

Comment: After search on google i found that if i set smoothing properties of VideoElement to true then video will render smoothly .But i am using SMILPlugin to load smil url and createMediaElement method of mediaFactory which return SMILElement so i am not able to set smoothing property.How can i get VideoElement instance from  createMediaElement method of mediaFactory.                                   var resource:URLResource = new StreamingURLResource(url);  mediaElement = mediaFactory.createMediaElement(resource);

Comment: That I do not know, that isn't related to JW Player.